# Rails: Combine link_to with #send to dynamically create link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found this code in the AdminHelper module of the app I am currently working on, and find it hard to understand what exactly is going on, and why it works.

`link_to item_type, send("admin_#{item_type.underscore}_path", item_type)`

(`item_type` holds the name of a model, mostly "Order")

Trying to get a clue by substituting it in the console didn't work but threw errors. But the code works fine.

Would someone be so kind to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You get the errors in rails console because the url_helpers are not included there. You can include it urself

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

then

```
send("admin_#{item_type.underscore}_path", item_type)
```

should work as expected it the console

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot that as I tried it in a bit of a hurry. But the main question was not why it didn't work in the console, but how this code creates the correct link.

Comment: simply because the helpers are not included in rails console by default. btw u could access them thru app and helper methods as well like app.root_path or helper.link_to etc. I dunno the reason not to include them in console though